# Make custom action for thunar to reduce images to 1024x768

Tags: thunar, thunar-custom-actions

I want to make a thunar custom action that would reduce an image to 1024x768.

This works from the command line.

```
convert -resize 1024X768 smaller.jpg small.jpg
```

I have this so far.

convert -resize 1024X768 %f

Answer (score 0):

The command you found and cited above uses the [convert](https://imagemagick.org/script/convert.php) app which is part of the [imagemagick](https://imagemagick.org/index.php) package.

To add that to Thunar, launch Thunar, do **Edit** , then click **Configure custom actions…** to go to the [Custom Actions Manager](https://duncanlock.net/blog/2013/06/28/useful-thunar-custom-actions/), where you can create, edit or delete your custom actions. Enter a new custom action of `convert -resize 1024X768 %n.jpg %n.jpeg` then click **OK** to save the export to the same filename ending in .JPEG .

Comment: It does not work. convert -resize requires 2 arguments. And the arguments would need to be "different" in that the 1st argument is the original file name while 2nd argument is the new name. I hope that made sense.

Comment: Try revised answer above

Comment: Sorry for the late response, but it does not work. @K7AAY